# Yii2 - prevent behavior on insert

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have this behavior in my model:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'styles' => [
                'class' => ImageStyleBehavior::className(),
                'path' => \Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/files/userphotos/styles',
                'url' => \Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/files/userphotos/styles',
                'attribute' => 'photo',
                'styles' => [
                    '300x300' => [$this, 'style300'], //can be any valid callable
                    '100x100' => [$this, 'style100'], //can be any valid callable
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```

The photo have default value of **noavatar.png**, and when I try to insert, I get this error:

```
Exception 'Imagine\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to open image /var/www/c2c/Care2Shine/www/files/userphotos/'
```

Is there a way for me to prevent behavior on insert actions?

Comment: overriding beforeSave() does not help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove specific named behaviors by detaching them:

```
$model->detachBehavior('styles');
```

Or, if it's the only behavior, you can just detach all:

```
$model->detachBehaviors();
```

To ensure you only detach on insert, check `isNewRecord` property.

Answer (score 0):

Does the ImageStyleBehavior extend the [AttributeBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-attributebehavior.html) ? in that case you should be able to use:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'attribute1',
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'attribute2',
             ],
             'value' => function ($event) {
                  return 'some value';
             },
        ],
    ];
}
```